# compare the differences between the contents of two different files

Tags: files

I have two excel sheets both having lakhs (hundreds of thousands) of records.
I want to compare if the records present in file1 is also present in file2 or not.
Also I want to check what all are the different records which are present in file1 and are not in file2.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so pure LibreOffice questions are off-topic here as well. However, on http://stackoverflow.com, a sister site to AskUbuntu, they're very good at all programming questions, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your questions if they are similar sheets:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28383/tool-to-compare-2-excel-sheets-in-linux

If it doesn't solve, could you please clarify exactly how the data is ordered/organized in those sheets?